# How to find the last updated table oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle11g, last-modified

I want to know what are the table got updated at last when I am sending some values from front end to the database, there is one way is to see the query layer, but it will take time so is there any way to find the **last updated table in oracle 11g?**

Comment: Check this out: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2095.htm

Comment: I saw the web site but what are the syntax to use DBA_TAB_MODIFICATIONS and USER_TAB_MODIFICATIONS

Comment: SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_MODIFICATIONS ;